# TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to make a code using re to store my mail in a file and at startup check if it is in that file othervise ask me to type it in again

I`ve tried putting self before the function name in line 28 (error)

```
import re

class login(object):
    def check(self):
        self.mail = r"([\w\.-]+)@([\w\.-]+)([\w\.-]+)"
        with open('login.txt', 'r') as self.myfile:
            self.line1 = self.myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        with open('username.txt', 'r') as self.usr:
            self.line2 = self.usr.read().replace('\n', '')
        if re.findall(self.mail, self.line1):
            goon()
        else:
            log()
        self.myfile.close()

    def goon(self):
        import assistant #another code to exec.

    def log(self):
        self.file = open("login.txt", "w")
        self.file.truncate(0)
        self.data = input("Your email: ")
        self.file.write(self.data)
        self.file.close()
        l.goon()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        check() #error
        log()
        goon()
```

Comment: Dude, where's your instance?

Comment: unindent, create an instance and call methods on that instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe *direct* reason you got the error is because you indented your "main" program, and made it a method of the class.

Pull it back to the left margin.  Then, to use the class code, you have to create an instance of the class.  This is the `self` that comes as a implicit argument to each method call.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = login()
    obj.check() #error
    obj.log()
    obj.goon()
```